# Does transformer with load drain more power from source than just load?

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's consider AC source of $\rm 12\ V$ and load of $\rm 12 \ Ohm$. Current is $1\ A$ and power is $\rm 12\ W$.

Now, we have the same source and the same load, but now is an  ideal transformer in path with ratio of turns $p=1/100$.

Then current through load should be :

$I=U_{\rm source}/p×R_{\rm load}=100\ \rm A$

And power is :

$\frac {U_{\rm source}I_{\rm load}}{p}=120 000\ \rm W$

So, it seems that transformer with load drains more power from source than just load directly connected to source. Am I right ?

If so, it also means that source, which do not kill me directly, can kill me through transformer ?

Answer (score 2):

A load is normally given in units of power.  A resistance becomes a load when you apply a particular voltage.

So, no, the load (power) doesn't change across an ideal transformer.  But the power across a resistance does vary as you change the voltage.

It is definitely possible for a transformer to make an ideal voltage source more dangerous.  I just wouldn't use the term "load" in describing that scenario.